# How can i open Google Maps app using Webview

Tags: android, google-maps, webview

so i have this app which loads a Webview directly in the app (which means it doesn't open the browser outside the app but embedded)

now on the webpage i have a link to googlemaps. i would like to click on the link and make this link open the original Google Maps app installed on the phone instead of opening the link in the embedded webview.

is this possible?

my actual webview setting:

```
webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 10 * 1024 * 1024 );
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/cache" );
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT );
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

Comment: Not sure but shouldn't be any problem. The Google Maps app recognizes links that belong to google maps, and should prompt you with the question if you want to open it in the browser or the app. Make sure you have it installed and you never putted your browser to be the default.

Comment: have you tried below [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/android_v3)

Comment: @StefandeBruijn for some reason when i click the link it opens the map within the webview.. if i remove   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); from the configuration then i start the app it asks me if i want to use the browser or chrome which makes the app exit to the browser and at that point if i click the link it asks me to open it with maps.. i don't understand

Comment: @YogeshTatwal i will look in the page you sent if i can understand how i can do what i am looking for..